# Unable to correct if statement for casino style balance

Tags: javascript

Rookie javascripter here, I am attempting to create a dice game for a casino in which the user is required to place a bet on which number the dice will land on. I know I need to use a if statement to determine whether or not the guess was correct and to either multiply or subtract the users stake from the total balance. I have been trying to solve this problem for a while now and haven't seemed to make much progress.

I believe this is the basic structure for the HTML that is required.

```
 <html>

        <h1>Rolling the Die</h1>

        <h4>Can You Guess Correctly?</h4>

    <div id="die1" class="dice"></div>
    <br>       
        <form>
            Guess: <input type="number" name="guess" id="guess" min="1" max="6">
            Stake: <input type="number" name="stake" id="stake">
            <br>
            <br>
            Balance: <span id="balance">1000</span>
        </form>
    <br>
    <button onclick="rollDice()">Roll Dice</button>

    </div>  <!---end of wrapper--->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="dice.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

However, my main issue is with the javascript file as I seem to be unable to make the if statement function as it should.

```
 //function called to initiate the roll

function rollDice() {
'use strict'
var balance = 1000; //declares balance
var guess = document.getElementById("guess");   //takes the users guess
var stake = document.getElementById("stake");   //takes the users stake
var die1 = document.getElementById("die1");     //provides the input for the die
var d1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;     //generates a random number between 1 and 6
die1.innerHTML = d1;    //displays the number generated by the die

//if statement to determine whether the users guess was correct and calculate balance

if (d1 == guess) {     
    balance = balance + (stake * 5);
} else {
    balance = balance - stake;
}
}
```

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually get the `value` of your textboxes, not the textboxes themselves.

For Example, instead of using

```
var guess = document.getElementById("guess");
```

use

```
var guess = document.getElementById("guess").value;
```

Also, you reset the `balance` to `1000` every time the button is clicked.  You'll need to store the `balance` as a running total and print it back out to the HTML at the end.  Currently, even if you calculate the `balance` correctly, you aren't doing anything with it.

Comment: Apart from that, is the rest of the code viable or is there any areas that need to be coded differently?

Comment: part of being a good programmer is learning to troubleshoot your code.  Take some time to implement the suggestions here, and then ask a new question if you still aren't able to work out the code.  Don't just expect people to write your entire routine for you.